# Packages required for website deployment using apache on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, webserver, nodejs

This is quite a broad question, but assuming I need to create an *Ubuntu 20.04 Server* which hosts a website using `httpd` and created using *Node.js* and *React*, which packages do I need to install in order to run it?

I know how to configure the *Apache* server itself once I have all the files I need to host the website, but I don't know which programs, environments and packages to install and from where.

For example: packages such as [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2).

Would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Way too broad a question.

Answer (score 0):

To install the Apache server packages on Ubuntu 20.nn

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install the apache2 package

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

If you are have the firewall enabled list your firewall applications profiles..

```
sudo ufw app list
```

Which will give you something like..

```
Available applications:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  OpenSSH
```

Now choose which one you want Apache..
e.g.
sudo ufw allow Apache

Job done

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I was asking about..